# How to write a function that calculates squares of integers and adds them to a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function that takes one integer less than 15 and determines squares of all integers from 1 to that number (including). And Puts them into a dictionary, where the keys are the integers and values are the squares. The function must show a warning if the input number is greater than 15 and compute nothing.

This is what I have so far. I don't know how to fix it. Please help

```
a=1
squared=a**2
first_dict={'a':'a**2'}

while a<15:
    print(a**2)
    a=a+1
if a>15:
    print("Warning: Input number is greater than 15")
    print("0")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not define a function, you need to do it like this:

```
def get_squares(n):

    if n > 15:
        print("n greater than 15")
        return None

    result = {}

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result[i] = i ** 2

    return result



r1 = get_squares(4)
print(r1)

get_squares(16)
```

And the for loop can be replaced with a list comprehension like:

```
return {i: i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)}
```

Which executed in the console will yield:

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
n greater than 15
```

Comment: Shouldn't really have given the OP the full homework there. They apparently didn't understand the assignment. I doubt they have gotten around to dict comprehensions yet.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform true, but at least the OP tried a solution. Offering the right solution will provide him a reflection on how to do it right. We're not here to assess the knowledge base in programming for the OP's but to answer their dilemmas. As for the list comprehension I edited my answer exemplification with both a forloop and a comprehension.